# Eclipse Maven debug - source not found

Tags: eclipse, debugging, maven, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a JUnit test case within a Maven project in Eclipse on my local machine and I am getting a "Source not found" error on my own test class. I went through all the other similar threads that I could find about the problem, but to the best of my understanding none of them addresses exactly my same problem, nor a solution for it. So here is the detail of what I have done:

1. Created a run configuration with the goals "-Dmaven.surefire.debug -Dtest=MyTestClass test"
2. Created a remote Java application that connects to localhost:5005. Added the base folder for the project in the "Source" tab.
3. Setup a breakpoint in MyTestMethod in MyTestClass. MyTestMethod has the @Test tag.
4. Run the run configuration in 1. The application stops listening on port 5005.
5. Debug the remote Java application in 2. The debugger window pops up and I see the thread with the stack trace of the classes where things are stopped. The debugger is stopped at the breakpoint that I setup. I can see the variables in this class and in other classes as well, but I get "Source not found" for MyTestClass. If I do "Edit source lookup path", my project is there as I added it in 2.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. As an alternative, I have also tried to create another run configuration with -DforkMode=never. But if I try to debug that, I get the following error:

```
ERROR context.TestContextManager: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
 [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@2a46b75b]
 to prepare test instance [MyTestClass@8afcd0c]
```

Thanks.