# Debuggin Vert.x-Maven-Projekt inside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, vert.x

I am currently developing an Vert.x Application inside Eclipse with maven. I did the Projekt-Setup like descripted here: http://vertx.io/maven_dev.html

Everything went fine, the project builds succesfully and the server gets started successfully in debug mode via the maven launch configuration with the goal: *package vertx:runMod*

However, if i set a breakpoint, the debugger stops at the right position and showing me the right stacktrace but it doesnt show me the line inside the source. instead of that it shows the infamous "Source not found"-screen with the "Edit Source Lookup Path"-Button.
The funny thing about this is that this also happens when the breakpoint is inside one of my own java files.
I can also navigate into the source of for example *vertx-core-2.0.0-final-sources.jar* via STRG-Left click on a vert.x class . After doing this i can see the debug-Infos on Variables ect. via mouse-over as usual. If i double click on the stack again eclipse changes back to the "source not found"-screen-tab again.

I also tried to run the maven goal "clean eclipse:eclipse" on my Project as suggested here: [Run Vertx in an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277301/run-vertx-in-an-ide) with no success.

I also tried all suggestions from here: [Eclipse Maven debug - source not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106495/eclipse-maven-debug-source-not-found) with no success

I think it has something to do with the way the application gets launched. (via vert.x Container-Instance out of maven goal)

Its Eclipse Luna (4.4) with m2e-Plugin vers. 1.5 with maven 3.2.1, and vert.x 2.1

Any Help would be great. THX in advance

Answer (score 0):

At least i found out how to debug into my own source files. I simply had to generate the source.jar for my project when it gets installed via the maven goal. I added the following to my pom under the `<plugins>` -section

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After that i linked this generated source-jar-file to my debugger via the "Edit Source Lookup Path"-Button (this has to be done only the first time)

The flaw about this is, if i change a single line in my source files i have to rebuild the whole projekt including the source.jar via maven -install. If i am not doing this the debugger ends up in wrong line numbers.

I also didnt found out how to debug into the classes that are inside my dependency-jars. So at least this isnt solved yet.